# How to assign multiple constants within one macro call

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

I want to assign multiple constants within one macro call. But the code below only assigns the last constant, the constants which where defined before are not available.

```
; notes.lisp
(defconstant N_oct0 0)

(defmacro N_defheight(_oct _note _offset)
  `(defconstant ,(read-from-string (concatenate 'string _note _oct))
    ,(+ (eval (read-from-string (concatenate 'string "N_oct" _oct)))
     _offset)))
(defmacro N_octave(_octave)
  `(N_defheight ,_octave "c"   0)
  `(N_defheight ,_octave "c#"  1)
  `(N_defheight ,_octave "des" 1)
  `(N_defheight ,_octave "d"   2)
  `(N_defheight ,_octave "d#"  3)
  `(N_defheight ,_octave "es"  3)
  `(N_defheight ,_octave "e"   4)
  `(N_defheight ,_octave "f"   5)
  `(N_defheight ,_octave "f#"  6)
  `(N_defheight ,_octave "ges" 6)
  `(N_defheight ,_octave "g"   7)
  `(N_defheight ,_octave "g#"  8)
  `(N_defheight ,_octave "as"  8)
  `(N_defheight ,_octave "a"   9)
  `(N_defheight ,_octave "a#"  10)
  `(N_defheight ,_octave "b"   10)
  `(N_defheight ,_octave "h"   11))

(N_octave "0")
```

After loading the file in sbcl, I have only the h0 constant, but none of the c0..b0 constants.

```
$ sbcl
This is SBCL 1.0.40.0.debian, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.
* (load "notes")

T
* h0

11
* c0

debugger invoked on a UNBOUND-VARIABLE in thread #<THREAD
                                                   "initial thread" RUNNING
                                                   {1002C34141}>:
  The variable C0 is unbound.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:QUIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV C0 #<NULL-LEXENV>)
0]
```

So how can I change the macro to execute all `defconstant` calls, not only the last one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to expand to a `progn` form

```
(defmacro N_octave(_octave)
  `(progn
     (N_defheight ,_octave "c"   0)
     (N_defheight ,_octave "c#"  1)
     (N_defheight ,_octave "des" 1)
     (N_defheight ,_octave "d"   2)
     (N_defheight ,_octave "d#"  3)
     (N_defheight ,_octave "es"  3)
     (N_defheight ,_octave "e"   4)
     (N_defheight ,_octave "f"   5)
     (N_defheight ,_octave "f#"  6)
     (N_defheight ,_octave "ges" 6)
     (N_defheight ,_octave "g"   7)
     (N_defheight ,_octave "g#"  8)
     (N_defheight ,_octave "as"  8)
     (N_defheight ,_octave "a"   9)
     (N_defheight ,_octave "a#"  10)
     (N_defheight ,_octave "b"   10)
     (N_defheight ,_octave "h"   11)))
```

Your macro code is instead computing all expansions and throwing them away except the last one (as always happens for all forms except last one in a function body).

Note that probably this is one of the case in which `eval-when` comes into play but I cannot really suggest anything about it because I've yet to truly understand all its intricacies (and I'm not even sure I want to :-) )

Comment: Aargh, I tried `(defmacro N_octave(_octave) (progn \`(N_defheight ...` before

Answer (score 5):

Other answers already pointed out the correct solution: to use PROGN.

**Here some remarks about 'style':**

```
(defmacro N_defheight(_oct _note _offset)
  `(defconstant ,(read-from-string (concatenate 'string _note _oct))
      ,(+ (eval (read-from-string (concatenate 'string "N_oct" _oct)))
          _offset)))
```

- Variables with leading underscore have what purpose? This not common Lisp practice in Common Lisp
- READ-FROM-STRING might be replaced by INTERN and STRING-UPCASE.
- You might want to control the package for the symbol generated by INTERN (or READ-FOR-STRING).
- EVAL can be replaced by SYMBOL-VALUE
- CONCATENATE could be replaced by FORMAT: (format nil "N-OCT~a" oct)
- for a defining macro, DEF should be the beginning of the name. That's just a convention.

example:

```
(defmacro N_octave(_octave)
  `(progn
      (N_defheight ,_octave "c"   0)
      ...
      (N_defheight ,_octave "h"   11))
```

Above could be simplified with a simple iteration:

```
`(progn
   ,@(loop for (note offset) in '(("c" 0) ("c#" 1) ... ("h" 11))
           collect (list 'defheight octave note offset)))
```

or using MAPCAR

```
`(progn
   ,@(mapcar (lambda (desc)
               (destructuring-bind (note offset) desc
                 (list 'defheight octave note offset)))
             '(("c" 0) ("c#" 1) ... ("h" 11))))
```

The effect is less typing and the important symbols are written only once.
One has to decide what is better: many similar looking statements or a small program transforming a data description.

**But there is another problem: the data is coded into the macro.**

This is wrong. A macro should do the code transformation and not contain data. Again, you can do everything, but good Lisp requires to have some feeling for programming style. I would put the notes and offsets as a list into a variable and use that in the macro, or provide it as a parameter:

```
(defvar *notes-and-offsets*
  '(("c" 0) ("c#" 1) ... ("h" 11)))

(defoctave (octave notes-and-offsets)
  `(progn
     ,@(mapcar (lambda (desc)
                 (destructuring-bind (note offset) desc
                   (list 'defheight octave note offset)))
               (eval notes-and-offsets))))

(defoctave "0" *notes-and-offsets*)
```

Now there is another problem. We define constants with names like `C0`. A constant in Lisp always refers to the global constant value. Rebinding is not allowed. That means that C0 is no longer a valid local variable name in your program. If you know that you will never use C0 as a variable name, that's fine - but this problem may not be known later during maintenance. For this reason, it is good style to put plus signs around names of constants like this: `+C0+`. Again, just a convention. You can also use your own specialized naming convention, which should not clash with your names for variables. like `NOTE-C0`.

If your intention is to always use an identifier like `c0` as a global name for a constant note value, then you don't have a problem - you just need to understand that then with DEFCONSTANT, you can't use `c0` no longer as a variable. It might be a good idea to have your own package, then.

Next: when you want to use variables when computing a macro expansion, then you need to make sure that the variables have values. Either load a file before or use EVAL-WHEN.

This leads to this code:

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (defvar *n-oct0* 0)
  (defvar *notes-and-offsets*
    '((c   0) (c#  1) (des 1) (d   2)
      (d#  3) (es  3) (e   4) (f   5)
      (f#  6) (ges 6) (g   7) (g#  8)
      (as  8) (a   9) (a# 10) (b  10)
      (h  11)))
  ) ; end of EVAL-WHEN

(defmacro defheight (oct note offset)
  `(defconstant ,(intern (format nil "~a~a" note oct))
     (+ ,(intern (format nil "*N-OCT~a*" oct))
        ,offset)))

(defmacro defoctave (octave notes-and-offsets)
  `(progn
     ,@(mapcar (lambda (note offset)
                 (list 'defheight octave note offset))
               (mapcar #'first (eval notes-and-offsets))
               (mapcar #'second (eval notes-and-offsets)))))

(defoctave 0 *notes-and-offsets*)
```

Comment: Sometimes I wonder why Lisp is not more mainstream. But soon it comes the answer: it is a language for the smart.

Comment: Thank you @Rainer, I'll rewrite the program at this weekend.

Answer (score 2):

Several statements are not concatenated this way in Lisp. Try to use the `progn` construct:

```
(defmacro N_octave(_octave)
    `(progn (N_defheight ,_octave "c" 0)
            (N_defheight ,_octave "c#" 1)
            ... ))
```